How to save files to a directory using FileSystemDirectoryHandle?
I'm trying to look for some documentation on FileSystemDirectoryHandle and if it is possible to save files to the opened directory. I've been searching for a couple hours now, any help will be appreciated.
-Alex
I tried searching on google but I've only found base overviews of the api. And I've tried looking at the returned object itself

It should depend on the server you're using. In a browser the script does not have access to the user filesystem. "This interface will not grant you access to the users' filesystem. Instead, you will have a virtual drive within the browser sandbox" from MDN File System Web API. But if you're using NodeJS (or any other JS interpreter) you may indeed access the local/remote filesystem. See NodeJS File System module for more details.

There are some extensions on browsers that allow specific sites to access the users' local filesystem though. But It's a whole other subject and a very dangerous one (because you can accidentally open the users' device to external attacks).

@KLASANGUI thanks for the pointer. I just remembered that vscode.dev has the system I'm looking for. I'm going to see if I can get a lead there.

I found an answer of at this github repository https://github.com/leon/labs-chrome-file-write
I just needed to add {create:true} as a parameter when searching for a file in the directory
